# Creating utility test function in Jest

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a typescript testing files where I test most of all whether some function was called. I would like to create utility class which will recieve names of functions and run basic test toHaveBeenCalled(). It would look something like that:

```
export function callForSubscription(subscriptions: string [], component: any){
  subscriptions.forEach((subscription) => {
    it(`should call ${subscription}`, () => {
      component[subscription] = jest.fn();
      component.ngOnInit();
      expect(component.setDefaultValues).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
}
```

I would like to call this function in my spec.ts file f.e like that

```
callForSubscription(['setDefaultValues', 'subscribeToSortSave'], component);
```

where ´component´ is instance of the testing component. I´m always getting that component is undefined. Is something like that possible, that we pass some parameters to utility function and then it runs our tests? I tried upper code but I´m always getting component to be undefined. It looks like callForSubscription function was executed before instance of component was created.

Comment: I'm quite sure that you have race condition. `it` tests should be defined synchronously at the time when test file is evaluated. Component instance shouldn't exist at this time. It's unknown where you call callForSubscription but you can be sure it won't work as you want. You probably don't need to define `it` at all. Just do an assertion with `expect` inside a loop.

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks, it works if I put the function into ' it ' in my spec and after the deleting the ' it ' from utility function. But what in the case if I want to have headers from 'it' to know the name of function which was tested?

Comment: You have to either sacrifice headers or organize tests in more complicated way. If setDefaultValues, etc are predefined, you can declare `it` with `forEach` in `describe` scope and then pass `component` to them via shared context from a place where it was defined - you didn't show it while it's relevant, is it `beforeEach`? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62027162/3731501 for the explanation on common context.

Comment: Btw, as for function names, there is https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-expect-message to print them in assertions.

Comment: jest-expect-message is printed only in case if test fails. I would like to print test name in assertions. fe. When I had test it('call with proper first parameter', () .... i would like to print that message to assertions log (I mean test results). Or If I had 3 ´except´ functions within one ´it´, I would like to add some message to each ´expect´, not only for whole ´it´. Is it possible?

Comment: *only in case if test fails* - yes, that's what it's for. A message for passed test is a convenience, a meaningful message for failed test is a necessity. If you really need it, you can fork jest-expect-message and make it output the message with process.stdout.write if the assertion doesn't fail. Still, the output won't look like regular tests with checkmarks.

Comment: yes I was thinking about those checkmarks.. I wanted it to look like a regular tests. I´ve put those expect´s into forEach loop, but there is a problem that after the first test fails, it outputs only the message of this test. Is there any way how to test all cases and after that, print messages of all failed tests? Thank you

Comment: You need to try..catch all errors and rethrow them them together as an array or map.