# How to chain promises with multiple expections in jest

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, es6-promise

I am trying to find a clean way to write an integration test (unit test with jest which uses real resources) with jest using promise chaining but I can get my head around it.

In addition of actual nesting the promises correctly I also don't know how to solve those two issues:

- How to have different `expects` in different promises being picked up correctly by jest
- having always a teardown where the resources are cleaned up even if there are exceptions

There are 4 function I would like to chain, similar to the Act - Arrange - Assert pattern.
The problem is that those funktion have async calls to f.e. a database and can have expectation.

To have a better understanding here is some pseudocode how this could look in my head. This only should provide a better understanding of the issue.

```
const setupResources =  () =>  new Promise(resolve => {
  //async calls to a database to setup a test
  await dynamoDBClient.put(params).promise();
  // returns data which are necessary for the other steps
  resolve(data);
});

const act = (data) => new Promise(resolve => {
  // doing some stuff
  const otherdata = {data};
    // calling some endpoint asyc
   const result = await axios.post(
              `https://restapi.com/test`,
              JSON.stringify(otherdata),
          );
  // some expects
  expect(result.status).toBe(200);  

  // again some data which will be needed in the other steps
  resolve({someInformation: 'info', data}) ;
});

const assertIt = (data) => {
  const prarams = {/*db related data*/}
  new Promise(resolve=>{
      const dbdata = await dynamoDBClient.get(params).promise();

      // some expectation
      expect(dbdata).toBe(data.data);
      resolve();
 })

};

const tearDown = (data) => {
  // cleanup of data base trash which should always happen
  await dynamoDBClient.delete(data.params).promise();
};
```

The actual test should look something along those line if that makes sense.

```
it('test',()=>{
return setupResources()
        .then(act(data))
        .then(assertIt(data))
        .finally(teardown(data));
})
```

Comment: "expections" -> "expectations"? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async..await` is a substitute for raw promises, there's no need to use `then`. The use of `new Promise` with existing promises is an antipattern. One of problems that `async` function solves is that data that needs to be available down the promise chain doesn't need to be passed through the entire chain, it can be declared as a variable in a scope that is available for the chain.

It should be:

```
const setupResources = async () => {
  await dynamoDBClient.put(params).promise();
  ...
  return data;
});
```

And the test:

```
it('test', async ()=> {
  let data;

  try {
    data = await setupResources();
    ...
   } finally {
     await teardown(data);
   }
});
```

Setup and teardown is a task that `beforeEach` and `afterEach` blocks solve. If there's a need to extract them to reusable functions, common data can be shared via context object like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62583087/3731501).

Comment: This is a much better approach.

Comment: Thank you. Hope this helps the OP's case.

Comment: I implemented it with async await now. It does not look that nice but it is more readable thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need an async test, to do this you can write the following. Now the test will wait (by default 5 seconds) till everything is done and expected.

```js
it('test', (done) => { // note the "done" argument
return setupResources()
        .then(act(data))
        .then(assertIt(data))
        .finally(() => { teardown(data); done() });
})
```

Comment: ok, that solves the problem that there will an tearddown at the end right? But how to I pass the data within my function from an async call (which is also a promise) to the next function?

Comment: The use of done with promises in Jest is an antipattern. This often results in additional mistakes because it needs much more attention. In this specific case `done()` results in passed test even if there was an error.

Comment: Yeah, I think this can be done much better because the assertion is done inside a promise so technically this test has no assertions at all, for this to work well, the assertions need to happen in this test.

This would be much easier with the async await syntax to understand, in that case we wont need to use `done` as well.

Comment: @ziZimon, if you are running Jest can you write this using the async await syntax? It will work just fine with promises because it's really just syntax sugar for it. If you do that it will be much easier to pass one result from another and also get the bonus of the test case waiting for everything to complete.

Comment: so I could pass down the data which should be expected to the end and do all the `expects` there? But how do I call an async db request in the promise which needs the resulted data be passed to the next one with additional data.